# Q_INIT_RESOURCE not working

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, qt-resource

Im developing a static library, and I use a qrc file. I read the documentation and found, that I have to call `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` to make it work, but no success so far.

- I called `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` in main, directly after creating the `QApplication` (I tried different places too, such as directly before accessing it etc.)
- No namespace
- The ressource file is added to the Project file of the library
- The file itself works, if using in a normal Qt Application via resource
- I used `QDirIterator` to list all resource, but no matter what I add to the file, it won't appear

I don't now whats going wrong here. If code is requested, I can post some, but except of calling `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` and creating a `QFile` with the resource, there is nothing special about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I'm actually using two libraries, and one used the same name for it's resource file. That won't work. I solved the problem by changing the name of my ressource.

Comment: If you are using libraries with some resources, just create a qrc file, where ever you want. But this one thing you must don't forget: i the pro file of your executable app implement this piece of code: RESOURCES += ../../mydb/dbaccess/resources.qrc. Of course your path to qrc, not mydb/dbaccess... These RESOURCES += line, you can repeat  as often you want ;-)

Comment: Edit: unfortunately you're absolutely right: the names of the qrc files must be different!